# Executing Exchange PowerShell commands from a CMD Prompt using VBscript

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, cmd

I'm creating a VBScript that will run an Exchange PowerShell command from a command prompt. 
When I tried to run the script below, `expected end of statement` appeared.

```
Dim oShell 
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd.exe ""C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"" -psconsolefile ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\exshell.psc1"" -file ""C:\script\script.ps1"" "
```

Please help me on this one.

Comment: I'm sure there is more to this but it is redundant to call a shell from another shell in the case. I would remove the `cmd` component from this. Also, you dont say where the error is occurring. Naturally i would expect that to be on the 3rd line however are the `<br>`'s in you actually script? That would cause the errors?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not just use PowerShell. In your case Cscript call Cmd that call PowerShell ?

Answer (score 1):

(1) The `<br>` must go.

(2) To avoid your quotes going ot of sync as in

```
... -file """C:\script\script.ps1" "
```

use a more structured way of building complex strings:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim oShell : Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Dim sCmd   : sCmd       = Join(Array( _
     "%comspec%" _
   , "/c" _
   , qq("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe") _
   , "-psconsolefile" _
   , qq("C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\exshell.psc1") _
   , "-file" _
   , qq("C:\script\script.ps1") _
))
WScript.Echo sCmd
```

output:

```
cscript 26477799.vbs
%comspec% /c "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -psconsolefile "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Bin\exshell.psc1" -file "C:\script\script.ps1"
```

Comment: I need to call the exshell.psc1 file to run or read the .ps1 file.